# body-perser is not parsing my request in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to use Controller here.

This is my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const routes = require('./Routes/route');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use('/', routes);

// support parsing of application/json type post data
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//support parsing of application/x-www-form-urlencoded post data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

var server = app.listen(8081);
```

This is my route.js:

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

const controller = require('../Controllers/controller');

router.get('/counter', controller.showCount);
router.post('/addcount', controller.addCount);

module.exports = router;
```

This is my controller.js:

```
    const db = require('../db-connect');

const showCount = (req, res) => {
    if(db.state === 'disconnected'){
        res.send('Server not connected');
    }
    else{
        db.query('select * from Count', (err, rows, fields) => {
            if (err) throw err

            res.send(rows);
        });
    }
};

const addCount = (req, res) => {
    console.log(typeof(req.body));
    res.send(req.body);
}

module.exports = {showCount, addCount};
```

Problem:
[It seems like requests are not being parsed. Not sure why.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTsZO.png)

I am using post man to send request. I am sending data as 'form-data' by postman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must add `app.use('/', routes);` under the bodyParser middleware

```js
// support parsing of application/json type post data
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//support parsing of application/x-www-form-urlencoded post data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use('/', routes);
```

Comment: Okay 'x-www-form-urlencoded' worked but not the 'form-data' in postman.